# Redirecting on login with Firebase Authentication and AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication, angularfire

**Issue**: On login, I would like to redirect the user to a new page. I am trying to pass `$state` to my controller, so I can do `$state.go()`, but I get an error of `Cannot read property 'go' of undefined`.

I am using Firebase's login with Email and password, Angular 1.5.8, ui-router and AngularFire.

Factory

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
  }
]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "$rootScope", '$state',
  function($scope, Auth, $firebaseArray, $rootScope, $state) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;

    $scope.createUser = function() {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      // Create a new user
      Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password, $scope.name)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
          $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + firebaseUser.uid;
          const uid = firebaseUser.uid;
          const dbref = firebase.database().ref().child('users/'+uid);
          const userInst = {}
          dbref.update({id:uid, info: {name: $scope.name}});
        }).catch(function(error) {
          $scope.error = error;
        });
    };
  $scope.signIn = function(){
    Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function(firebaseUser){
      console.log(firebaseUser.uid);
      $state.go('dashboard')
    })
    .catch(function(error) {

      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
    });
  }
    $scope.deleteUser = function() {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      $scope.auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
      $scope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;
    });

      // Delete the currently signed-in user
      Auth.$deleteUser().then(function() {
        $scope.message = "User deleted";
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error;
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$firebaseArray` is missing.
Inject dependency `$firebaseArray` in the controller.

```
app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth", "$firebaseArray","$rootScope", '$state',
  function($scope, Auth, $firebaseArray, $rootScope, $state) {

   // CODE   

  }
]);
```